# Looking for an example of the new Android API setMediaButtonReceiver

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

Currently  I am using

```
  mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mRemoteControlResponder);
```

but this is now **deprecated in 5.0** and replaced by `setMediaButtonReceiver`. There are 5 links in Google all pointing to developer.android.com.

Has anyone used this yet? If so can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this page: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-0/android/media/session/MediaSession.java It is a rather large example of the complete flow.Here one of the most relevant parts

> Set a pending intent for your media button receiver to allow  restarting playback after the session has been stopped. If your app is started in this way an android.content.Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON intent will be sent via the pending intent.
>
> Parameters: nullmbr The android.app.PendingIntent to send the media button event to.

```
     public void More ...setMediaButtonReceiver(@Nullable PendingIntent mbr) {
         try {
              mBinder.setMediaButtonReceiver(mbr);
         } catch (RemoteException e) {
             Log.wtf(TAG, "Failure in setMediaButtonReceiver.", e);
         }
     }
```

Comment: The first link is correct but I'm not sure why you included the rest as the OP is about NOT using *MediaButtonEventReceiver.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was sleeping I think.. Did the link help you?

Comment: Link not responding